# ELB with a CNAME and 2 IIS servers

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis, amazon-elb

I have the following setup in AWS:

1. 1 ELB with HTTP and HTTPS listeners
2. ELB forwards to two Windows servers running IIS that act as CDN servers. CDN "website" is set up
   as the default site (HTTP only - I want the ELB to handle the SSL
   termination)
3. CNAME is setup via our DNS provider (NOT Route 53) to
   point to the ELB A record

When I use the ELB domain to retrieve a CDN item, it works fine. However if I use the CNAME domain (cdn3.example.com) then it comes back with a 404 error for the same CDN item that was retrieved earlier using the ELB domain.

This is using HTTP - at some point I want to introduce HTTPS and Cloudfront but that's for another day.

EDIT: DNS changes have had long enough to propagate through

Comment: What do you see in the access logs for both the ELB and your windows server? Also, it is really worth skipping this and using Cloudfront.

Comment: Yes but the idea is that Cloudfront sits in front of the ELB. We have dynamic image resizing so potentially need more than one instance to handle the load. Also, to use HTTPS, the ELB needs a SSL certificate and to do that it needs a CNAME to a domain we control for the certificate issuer

Comment: OK we can save cloudfront for another day. :) What do your logs show? That will tell us what's happening. I suspect your web server might be getting tripped up somehow.

Comment: So when using the ELB domain - the requests go through fine and the requests are logged as you'd expect in the IIS logs with a 200 status code with the IP address of the ELB. Using the CNAME, the requests don't seem to logged at all, implying the ELB is killing off the request and not forwarding it?

Comment: Enable the access logs on the ELB and we'll see if it's making it that far. If not then perhaps it's something as simple as a typo in the DNS record and its hitting some other server/ELB.

Comment: The cname should point to the public dns name of the ELB not the A record.

"CNAME records must always be pointed to another domain name, never to an IP address." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record

Comment: @GeorgeMWhitaker thanks for all your help - turned out to be an issue with the CNAME record - didn't have a trailing . as required